# Fedora networking not working correctly but only on one network

Tags: networking, fedora

I have a very odd networking problem. When using Fedora, I have problem with network only when connected to one specific network (BTW it's ADSL) and no other OS has that problem (I have 2 PCs and both have the problem with Fedora, but on Windows it's OK everytime). The problem does not occur on the other networks.
The problem is:

1. Git push sometimes doesn't work (on some remotes it works, on some it freezes even for 10 minutes)
2. Facebook will not load after some time (after starting the computer, facebook is responding well, after some time it just freezes and stays loading. After some time (2 minutes +-), firefox just stops loading anymore). Pinging facebook works well.

Comment: Need a bit more detail. The "network is not working" description you give sounds like it *is* working, but slowly.

Comment: Sorry, but no, it is not the slow internet that cause the problem. It just hangs and never ends/loads these things

Comment: In all cases, are network interface IP addresses *and* DNS server IP addresses configured via DHCP?
When 'git push' "freezes", what happens if you 'git clone' the same repo into a separate/independent/tmp directory?

Comment: @Mathew, "just hangs, never ends" is *not* a sign of "non working network", it is a sign of "network going extremely slow". Might be a egregious configuration problem (an idiotic firewall on the way, badly configured DNS/DHCP, ...)